# Flex swallowing \n and \r at the end of input

Tags: bison, flex-lexer

I'm trying to make Flex to swallow my \r\n characters at the end of my input. (this is an interpreter like CLI)

So far, I have no luck. I have the following rule:

swallow ([[:space:]]|\n)

and then
<*>{swallow};

But it doesn't seem have any affect. I also have the following RE for capturing string:

any ^[:space:]+

but this also captures the \r and \n at the end of the input.

Edit: Here's the complete l file.

```
%{
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "hmd.tab.h"
#include "cmd.h"
%}

%option noyywrap nounput noinput
%option reentrant bison-bridge
%option debug

digit [0-9]
integer [+-]?{digit}+
uinteger {digit}+
real [+-]?({digit}+[.]{digit}*)|({digit}*[.]{digit}+)
exp [+-]?({integer}|{real})[eE]-?{integer}
alpha [[:alpha:]]+
any [^[:space:]](.|\n)+
swallow ([[:space:]]|\n)


%x ZONE ZONE_ACTION ZONE_FIELD_SET ZONE_FIELD_GET VALUE SYSTEM
%x DEVICE DEVICE_ACTION DEVICE_FIELD_SET DEVICE_FIELD_GET
%x SENSOR SENSOR_SET SENSOR_GET SENSOR_VALUE
%x LOG

%%

    /*subsystems*/
<INITIAL>zone {
    BEGIN(ZONE);
    return (sys_zone);
}

<INITIAL>device {
    BEGIN(DEVICE);
    return (sys_device);
}

<INITIAL>sensor {
    BEGIN(SENSOR);
    return (sys_sensor);
}

<INITIAL>system {
    BEGIN(SYSTEM);
    return (sys_system);
}

<INITIAL>help {
    return (sys_help);
}

<INITIAL>exit|logout {
    return (sys_exit);
}

<INITIAL>ver|version {
    return (sys_ver);
}

<INITIAL>log {
    BEGIN(LOG);
    return (sys_log);
}

<INITIAL>{alpha} {
    yylval->name = strdup(yytext);
    return (cmd_other);
}

<ZONE>{uinteger} { /*zone id*/
    yylval->number = strtoll(yytext, NULL, 0);
    BEGIN (ZONE_ACTION);
    return (zone_id);
}

<ZONE>list {
    return (zone_list);
}

<ZONE>new {
    return (zone_new);
}

    /*Zone actions*/
<ZONE_ACTION>set {
    BEGIN (ZONE_FIELD_SET);
    return (zone_action_set);
}

<ZONE_ACTION>get {
    BEGIN (ZONE_FIELD_GET);
    return (zone_action_get);
}
<ZONE_ACTION>start {
    return (zone_action_start);
}
<ZONE_ACTION>stop {
    return (zone_action_stop);
}

<ZONE_FIELD_SET>name|stat|target_val|param|logic|log_entries|log_avg_method {
    yylval->name = strdup(yytext);
    BEGIN (VALUE);
    return (zone_field);
}

<ZONE_FIELD_GET>name|stat|target_val|param|logic|last_error|last_error_time|log_entries|log_avg_method {
    yylval->name = strdup(yytext);
    return (zone_field);
}

    /*Operations on device*/
<DEVICE>{uinteger} { /*device id*/
    yylval->number = strtoll(yytext, NULL, 0);
    BEGIN (DEVICE_ACTION);
    return (device_id);
}

<DEVICE>list {
    return (device_list);
}

<DEVICE>new {
    return (device_new);
}

<DEVICE_ACTION>set {
    BEGIN (DEVICE_FIELD_SET);
    return (device_action_set);
}

<DEVICE_ACTION>get {
    BEGIN (DEVICE_FIELD_GET);
    return (device_action_get);
}

<DEVICE_FIELD_SET>name|stat|vci|fid|chid|param|poll_timeout|log_timeout|log_entries|log_avg_method {
    yylval->name = strdup(yytext);
    BEGIN (VALUE);
    return (device_field);
}

<DEVICE_FIELD_GET>name|stat|vci|fid|chid|param|poll_timeout|log_timeout|log_entries|log_avg_method {
    yylval->name = strdup(yytext);
    return (device_field);
}

<SENSOR>set {
    BEGIN (SENSOR_SET);
    return (sensor_set);
}

<SENSOR>get {
    BEGIN (SENSOR_GET);
    return (sensor_get);
}

<SENSOR>{uinteger} { /*sensor id*/
    yylval->number = strtoll(yytext, NULL, 0);
    if (YY_START == SENSOR_SET) {
        BEGIN (SENSOR_VALUE);
    }
    return (sensor_id);
}

<SENSOR_VALUE>{real} {
    yylval->real = strtod(yytext, NULL);
    return (sensor_val);
}

<VALUE>{any} {
    yylval->name = strdup(yytext);
    printf("VALUE '%s'\n", yytext);
    return(cmd_value);
}

    /*System commands*/
<SYSTEM>restart {
    return(sys_restart);
}

<*>{swallow};
```

So one of the CLI input can be like this:

zone 2 set some_filed arbitrary string with spaces, newline, etc

Comment: If you have mulitple rules that can match, the one with the longest match matches.  Your `swallow` pattern only matches a single character, while the other one will match multiple whitespace characters (such as a `\r\n` pair)

Comment: What do you mean by "swallow?" Skip over?

Comment: You need to show us all your rules, as obviously a different one is being invoked here.

Comment: You need BEGIN INITIAL or at least BEGIN something else in your VALUE rule.

Comment: `<*>{swallow};` does not mean "match a {swallow} and ignore it". It means "match a {swallow} followed by a semicolon and then perform an undefined action." OK, actually Flex is forgiving; if you don't specify an action, which is technically illegal, Flex will assume you meant to do nothing. But it will require the semicolon in order for the match to apply. By the way `\n` is in `[:space:]` so `([[:space:]]|\n)` is several ways redundant. You could have just used `[[:space:]]`. if that's what you meant, in which case the alias `{swallow}` is just a distraction.

Comment: Thanks, yes, you are right, my {swallow} rule made no sense. However, I believe \n is NOT in [:space:]. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression.